# How to use split() to remove last destination in path?

Tags: java, split, directory, path

I have a list of paths and i need to remove the last directory of each path.

Path : "I:\Directory_1\Directory_2\Directory_3-Sometext"
I used the split method to remove everyting on the right side of the '-'

I've tried using split() removing one by one and then regrouping everything in one string.
I've tried splitting everyting on ("\") and using lenght()

```
//Removes text after '-'
String [] parts = path.split("-")
String partsA = parts[0]

String [] newParts = partsA.split("\\\\");
String partsB = newParts[newParts.length-1];

partsA = partsA.substring(partsA.length()-partsB.length(),partsA.length()+partsB.length());
```

I expect the ouput to be

> \Directory_1\Directory_2

without the last directory and the text

Comment: Should it just be `substring(0,partsA.length()-partsB.length())` in your scenario?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using string manipulation, you could use proper path/file objects, with the additional benefit that it can handle other types of paths (for example a unix path such as `/home/directory1`):

```
String f = "I:\\Directory_1\\Directory_2\\Directory_3-Sometext";
Path p = Paths.get(f);
Path parent = p.getParent();
System.out.println(parent.toString());
```

Comment: Didn't thought using getParent() really helpful . Thank you. Best regards

Answer (score 2):

You could also use Java's File API:

```
new File("I:\\Directory_1\\Directory_2\\Directory_3-Sometext").getParent();
```

This has the advantage of being OS indepenent...

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
String directory = "I:\\Directory_1\\Directory_2\\Directory_3-Sometext";
directory.substring(0, directory.lastIndexOf("\\"));
```

which outputs:

> I:\Directory_1\Directory_2